# Menu-left with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show and hide with toggle the entire side menu bar(#menu_links) when the browser is tunneled to less than 750px.

Does anyone know why the side menu bar (#menu_links) is not hidden by passing the edge of the browser when you click "#menu_button" when the browser size is less than 750?

https://menusel-169ba.firebaseapp.com/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu_links').css({ width: '50px' });
    $('.collapse-menu').addClass('hidden');

    $('ul#menu_links li').hover(function () {
        $('span', this).addClass('show');
        $('span', this).removeClass('hidden');
    }, function () {
        $('span', this).addClass('hidden');
        $('span', this).removeClass('show');
    });


  // Muesrta panel de CAMBIAR CONTRASEÑA
    $('a.test').on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    var timesClicked = 0;
    $("#menu_button").click(function () {
        timesClicked++
        if (timesClicked % 2 == 0) {
            $('#menu_links').animate({ width: '50px' }, 350);
            $('.collapse-menu').removeClass('show');
            $('.collapse-menu').addClass('hidden');

            $('ul#menu_links li').hover(function () {
                $('span', this).addClass('show');
                $('span', this).removeClass('hidden');
            }, function () {
                $('span', this).addClass('hidden');
                $('span', this).removeClass('show');
            });
        } else {
            $('#menu_links').animate({ width: '200px' }, 350);
            $('.collapse-menu').addClass('show');
            $('.collapse-menu').removeClass('hidden');

            $('ul#menu_links li').hover(function () {
            }, function () {
                $('span', this).addClass('show');
                $('span', this).removeClass('hidden');
            });
        }
        console.log(timesClicked % 2);
    });


    var menu_buttonVar = document.querySelector("#menu_button"),
        menu_linksVar = document.querySelector("#menu_links");


    // checkWidth() BREACK-POINTS
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();

        if (windowSize <= 750) {
            console.log("screen width is less than 480");
            menu_linksVar.style.left = "-50px";


            $('#menu_button').click(function () {
                $('#menu_links').animate({
                    left: '0px',
                }, 0);
            });
        } // END if

        else {
            console.log("screen width is greater than or equal to 960");
            menu_linksVar.style.left = "0px";
        }
    };

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
}); // END documentReady
```

Comment: Do your class `.show` and `.hidden` in css has `display: auto` and `display: none` respectively? Just for the sake of testing try `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: This are bootstrao clases but i thik all its about JS in this case

Comment: can u create a fiddle? since this is all JS code that you have shared.

Comment: Ok sorry: https://jsfiddle.net/5rxkrvps/

Comment: I would recommend using CSS `transform: translateX()` or `transform: translate3d()` to do the animation, just look into Off-canvas menus like [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/quJpi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my menu is ready and it works fine.
The next step is synthesize the code to work with the same functions but with less characters.

Here is the link:

https://menusel-169ba.firebaseapp.com/

Thank you.